# Password encryption with SHA1 gives weird output

Tags: c#, hash, passwords, sha1

So I was coding a simple login registration windows app on visual studio as I wanted to start learning again C#
I have this registration page with a few fields, the code is very simple, I didn't do anything related to validation.
I am basically trying to hash the password using SHA1 in c# and output in another textbox, but I am a getting some unknown characters

Here is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (username.Text.Trim()=="" || password.Text=="" ||     passwordc.Text=="" || fname.Text == "" || lname.Text == "" || birthday.Text ==    "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the fields!");

        }
        else if (password.Text!=passwordc.Text) {
            MessageBox.Show("Passwords don't match !");             
        }

        else
        {
            String passwd="";
            passwd = password.Text;


            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwd);
            SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] passbyte = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
            string pass = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(passbyte);
            textBox1.Text = pass;

        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOPit.png

Is there anything wrong or is this a normal hashing? I am kinda confused now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash is just a bunch of bytes. They're not meaningful characters. If you want to turn the hash into a textual form, you can use [Convert.ToBase64String()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string pass = Convert.ToBase64String(passByte);
```

Also, consider switching to SHA256. SHA1 is becoming easier and easier to crack as computing power increases. One common thing to do is to run the hashing process (the new hash becomes the password to hash) hundreds or thousands of times before storing it. It doesn't make too significant a difference in time for creating a hash to store, but it makes cracking the password take that many times longer.

Also, you'll want to start incorporating a random salt to each password to hash. This avoids rainbow table attacks and won't generate the same hash for identical passwords.

Comment: Thanks a lot worked like a charm ! 
But I was thinking that line 
string pass = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(passbyte) was the one to convert it into text, thats why I added it, is it wrong?

Comment: @Issam That only works if the bytes represent UTF8 characters. The hash result doesn't.

Comment: "Also, consider switching to SHA256" -- Not exactly.  The main security factor we require in password hashing is slow speed.  Designs like pbkdf2, bcrypt, and scrypt are more appropriate for this purpose, and they have salt already built into their designs.  See this [netsec thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/5ya6uw/multiple_vulnerabilities_discovered_in_dna/) for more info.

Comment: @TheGreatContini I don't know about the "main" factor, but it's certainly an important one. If it takes 5 minutes to generate a hash that's only 10 bytes long, a cracker is still going to have an easy time because there will be a higher chance of collisions. Going to one of the designs you mentioned will help, but really, the steps I mentioned (longer hash, longer compute time by a factor or thousands) accomplishes that already. And it's only a 3 character change for the OP to change the "1" to "256".